# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'merge_summary' error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tflearn

Long story short I have this problem where when I run the code it says that the module I use Tensorflow has no attribute 'merge_summary' The thing is that I don't even use merge_summary.

I have tried to uninstall tenserflow and it didn't work.

```py
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

import numpy
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import json
import random

with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data)
```

This should put a lot of text in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try **tf.compat.v1.summary.merge_all** as merge_summary is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`merge_summary` is deprecated.

use instead :

`tf.summary.merge`